# UNIX How do delete my unnecessary/excessive lines in my output?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My script is a mimic of the rm command, long story short. Can anyone point out the errors/unnecessary lines I have in my remove script that causes my output to produce excessive/irrelevant lines? The code works as intended but it produces all these unnecessary/excessive/duplicate lines. Output below is what looks like when I try to remove 2 files in the same line and do some other simple commands. Thank you in advance. I appreciate any help.

input: `sh remove file2 file4`
output:

```
Executed
Executed
cannot remove file4: no such file or directory
stat: cannot stat 'file4': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'file4': No such file or directory
Executed
mv: cannot stat 'file4': No such file or directory
File moved to recycle bin
```

```
#/bin/bash

function directory(){
if [ ! -d ~/deleted ]    
then    
         mkdir ~/deleted    
fi   
if [ ! -f ~/.restore.info ]
    then    
        touch ~/.restore.info    
fi    
}    

function movefile(){    
mv $1 ~/deleted/$1    
echo "file moved to recycle bin"    
}    

function error_conditions(){
#prints error messages and checks if file is in project directory   
if [ ! -f ~/project ]   
    then   
        echo "cannot remove $filename: no such file or directory"   
elif [ -d ~/project ]   
        then   
             echo "cannot remove $filename: is a directory"  
else  
    echo "missing operand"  
fi  
}   

function delete_file(){    
#gets inode for filename    
inode=$(stat -c%i $filename)    
filename=$1   
#pwd=$(readlink -e$filename)    
if $interactive   
    then    
        if [ $verbose = true ]; then   
            read -p "Are you sure you want to delete $filename?" i_input   
                  if [ $i_input == "y" ] || [ $i_input == "Y" ]    
                        then    
                     mv $filename ~/delete/${filename}_inode    
                     echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd>>~/.restore.info    
                    echo "$filename has been deleted"    
                         else    
                        echo "Nothing has been deleted"    
                     fi   
             else    
                read -p "Are you sure you want to delete $filename?" i_input    
                if [ $i_input == "y" ] || [ $i_input == "Y" ];    
                     then    
                     mv $filename ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode    
                     echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd>>~/.restore.info    
                         else    
                         echo Aborted   
                 fi    
             fi    
         elif $verbose    
             then    
                 mv $filename ~/deleted/${filename}_inode    
                 echo ${filename}_$inode:$inode:pwd>>~/.restore.info    
                 echo "$filename has been deleted."    
         else    
             mv $filename ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode    
             echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd>>~/.restore.info    
             echo Executed    
     fi    
     }    
     interactive=false    
     verbose=false    
    while getopts iv option    
     do    
       case $option in    
             i) interactive=true;;    
             v) verbose=true;;    
         esac    
     done   
    shift $[OPTIND-1]    
     for i in $*    
         do    
     filename=$i    
     baseline=$(basename $i)    
     if [ "$i" == "" ];    
         then    
            echo "No filename provided"    
        elif [ -d $filename ];    
             then    
                 if [ ! $recursive = true ];    
                     then    
                         echo "Directory name provided, please provide a file"    
                 fi   
         elif [ ! -f $filename ];   
             then    
                echo "File does not exist"    
       elif [ "$basefule" == "safe_rm" ]    
            then    
                echo "Attempting to delete safe_rm"    
       else    
            delete_file $filename    
         fi    
         done    

     #################################M A I N###############################   
    directory   
    error_conditions $*   
    delete_file $*   
    movefile $*
```

Comment: Please don't put line numbers in your code - it makes it much harder to read and debug. Also, please include the output *as text* inside your question.

Comment: I removed the line numbers. My output is a lot. That is why I attached snapshots of it. Sorry. Any suggestions/solutions for my issue?

Comment: Each of the outputs are less than a screenful, which is really not a lot. Please include them in the question.

Comment: I edited my question to put one of my outputs in my question as an example

Comment: Simple answer: identify the shell script lines that produce the messages and remove them or comment them out (with a `#`).   But you will need to do this yourself because "excessive and irrelevant" is subjective ... and you haven't told us what **you** mean by that.

Comment: Reconsider your requirements.When you want some version control/backup, you might want something like a `git` repository or ask your sysadmin for daily backups.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies *many* problems with the code.

Answer (score 1):

- Please indent properly.
- `for i in $*` should be `for i in "$@"` or simply `for i`.
- In general, variables should be quoted
  (e.g., `"$1"`, `"$i"`,
  `"$filename"`,
  `"$verbose"`, etc.)
- `$[expression]` is obsolete. 
  Use `$((expression))`.
- Your main loop calls

  ```
  delete_file $filename
  ```

  (line 100). 
  Your `delete_file` function sets

  ```
  filename=$1
  ```

  (line 35),
  which is somewhat redundant and therefore confusing.
- You set `baseline` but never use it. 
  You test (i.e., reference) `$basefule` without ever setting it. 
  Are these meant to be the same variable?
- The code says

  ```
  if [ ! -f ~/project ]
  then
      echo "cannot remove $filename: no such file or directory"
       ︙
  ```

  This is a ***very*** misleading message.
- You have a big comment that says “`M A I N`”,
  but the “main” code begins about 33 lines earlier.
- The code does

  ```
  for i in $*
      do
  filename=$i                             # This is an example of terrible indenting.
       ︙
           delete_file $filename
                ︙
       done
  ```

  but then, five lines later,

  ```
  delete_file $*
  ```

  so you’re processing the files twice. 
  So, even if `delete_file` succeeds the first time you call it,
  the file will be gone when you call it a second time.
- And, if you want to call a function (e.g., `delete_file`)
  with all the arguments to the script,
  you should use `"$@"` rather than `$*`.
- ***And,*** if you’re going to call `delete_file` with a list of filenames,
  then `delete_file` needs to iterate (loop) over those arguments. 
  Your `delete_file` function only looks at `$1`.